# Remove the smooth animation in Blender

Tags: animation

Is there a way to disable smooth transition on key-frame animation in Blender?

Lets say I have a character modeled in Blender and now wish to animate it.
I want this character to have really bizarre spazz-like animation that doesn't seem realistic.

So I'd like this characters arm to 'teleport' between frames. From up to down and so on. Right now, the key-frame system forces the hand to transport visibly to the location.

This also would open doors for animated textures as changing image on object using AnimAll add-on.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to set the interpolation type of the curves to ***Constant***.
[image]

If you're looking for a manequin, bizzare looking movement try the ***Bounce*** effect. 
[image]

Here's this dynamic effect applied to the head and a right hand of the model.
[image]

I also encourage you to test some other available types of interpolations, for the different (sometimes really amazing) movement types. Maybe one of them'll fit your needs.